# Powershell to fetch the Component Governance result from azure devops build pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-remoting

We have a requirement to fail the azure devops Build pipeline if you get a Component goverance alert om missing license information on that particular build. Is there any powersehll command topull the component  goveranace build result from pipeline and fail the build

Comment: Component Governance has an API, but it's almost completely undocumented.  This is the only published documentation I could find:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/governance

Comment: When I dug into the GitHub link at the bottom of that page, then browse around, I found this folder with some api samples:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/componentGovernance

I don't see anything there for alerts by build, just for settings and snapshots.

Comment: In our builds, I see an artifact added for component governance.  It's a file like `GovCompDisc_Manifest_\d+.json`.  But his doesn't contain any alerts.  I believe Alerts for component governance are all external to the build, i.e.  the build reports the packages it uses, then the packages may be marked as problematic at some point.

Comment: Instead of immediately failing the build, you would probably want a service that, based on alerts from component governance, adjusts the build quality for any build that used the problematic package.

Answer (score -1):

When you get a Component goverance alert om missing license information, you could write an error with the following code:

```
# Writes an error to build summary and to log in red text
Write-Host  "##vso[task.LogIssue type=error;]This is the error"
```

If you want this error to fail the build, then add this line:

```
exit 1
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: But issue is like in the from component governance output there is no specific  word to  filter the license missing alert...

Comment: How did you fetch the Component Governance result in powershell locally? This part seems out of DevOps's scope.

Comment: I seems like the question is more about getting results from Component Governance than about the mechanics of failing a build.

Comment: Component Governance is in DevOps scope.  It's just really poorly documented.